# Joomla - how to direct flow between pages

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I'm new to component development but I've read a lot online over the past month and I have the excellent Dexter/Landry book, "Joomla! Programming".

I'm really struggling with getting an understanding of how

1. data flows through the component and
2. control flows especially between views. I understand the 'high level' MVC concepts but I can't find a resource that brings this down to the level of actual methods/functions and data. Maybe someone who's had the same struggle could point me in the right direction ?

My most immediate problem is controlling flow between (form) views, eg, I want to 'Save' on view1 and be brought to view2. On entering data in view2 I want to 'Save' and be brought to view3 etc.

All help very much appreciated!

Comment: Are you more wondering about moving the data between views or about the redirect?

Comment: My most immediate problem is just moving between views but it needs to be part of the 'Save' from the first view. I can probably use set/getState to save key data between views if necessary but I just need to know the correct way to make the views 'flow'.  - Thanks !

Comment: Are you using the toolbar save or a form with submit?

Comment: It's a Submit button. I should have also mentioned I'm working on the front end.  - Thanks Elin.

Comment: If you look at the form MVC in the article view you will see that there is a `$return_page` property.  Also `<input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
     <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $this->return_page; ?>" />` in the template assigns this to the return field.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Elin. I tried that before and I tried it again now just to be sure, and it will not work for me. I've tried it with the return_page a straight URL, and the URL base64 encoded and urlencoded. In all cases the 'Save' is successful but brings me back to the list screen, not the one I wanted.

Comment: Can you please show your code and also var_dump $this->return_page to make sure it's correct? Also you'll have a lot more people helping you if you go to [joomla.se] the joomla stackexchange site.

Comment: Thanks @Elin. I'll be heading over to the Joomla Stackexchange. Dumping $this->return_page gets me the base64 encoded URL that I entered. Surprisingly, before I set $this->return_page  it contains an empty string. I need to learn more about the flow of control as mentioned in my original question.